# how to receive and send with same parameter name in JAVA SOAP

Tags: java, soap

I have a SOAP web service code as below:

```
public void sumAndMultiplyAndReference
(@WebParam(name = "firstnumber")int a,
 @WebParam(name = "firstnumber")int b,
 @WebParam(name = "referencenumber")int c
 @WebParam(name = "sum", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> sum,
 @WebParam(name = "multiply", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> multiply,
 @WebParam(name = "reference", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> reference){
sum.value = a + b;
multiply.value = a * b;
reference.value = c;
}
```

It is working fine. But what should be changed in the code such that, the request parameter name = referencenumber and reply parameter name be same?

Note: here- request parameter `name = referencenumber`

response parameter `name = reference`

Comment: Hi @raazan-kurunju, why did it not work for you? For me it worked fine without even using INOUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
package org.toto.bla;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import javax.xml.ws.Holder;
@WebService
public class WSTest {
    @WebMethod
    public void sumAndMultiplyAndReference(@WebParam(name = "firstnumber") int a, @WebParam(name = "secondnumber") int b,
                                           @WebParam(name = "referencenumber") int c,
                                           @WebParam(name = "sum", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> sum,
                                           @WebParam(name = "multiply", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> multiply,
                                           @WebParam(name = "referencenumber", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> reference) {
        sum.value = a + b;
        multiply.value = a * b;
        reference.value = c;
    }
}
```

And here is the generated XSD from this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:ns0="http://bla.toto.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://exporter.vas.asgs.atos.net/">
   <xsd:complexType name="sumAndMultiplyAndReferenceResponse">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="sum" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
         <xsd:element name="multiply" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
         <xsd:element name="referencenumber" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="sumAndMultiplyAndReference">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="firstnumber" type="xsd:int"/>
         <xsd:element name="secondnumber" type="xsd:int"/>
         <xsd:element name="referencenumber" type="xsd:int"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="sumAndMultiplyAndReferenceResponse" type="ns0:sumAndMultiplyAndReferenceResponse"/>
   <xsd:element name="sumAndMultiplyAndReference" type="ns0:sumAndMultiplyAndReference"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

You could also use the `INOUT` param type:
    package org.toto.bla;

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import javax.xml.ws.Holder;

@WebService
public class WSTest {
    @WebMethod
    public void sumAndMultiplyAndReference(@WebParam(name = "firstnumber") int a, @WebParam(name = "secondnumber") int b,
                                           @WebParam(name = "sum", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> sum,
                                           @WebParam(name = "multiply", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<Integer> multiply,
                                           @WebParam(name = "referencenumber", mode = WebParam.Mode.INOUT) Holder<Integer> c) {
        sum.value = a + b;
        multiply.value = a * b;
    }
}
```

Which generates the exact same XSD.

Comment: Thanks clapsus, it worked for me. exactly what i am looking for. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebParam.Mode.INOUT`, that way you will be able to use it in bi-directional way.

Read [from Apache about @WebParam](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/webservice-holder/README.html), below is excerpt.

> If the Holders were specified as WebParam.Mode.INOUT params, then the
>   client could use them to send data and the application as well. The
>   Holder instances would then be initialized with the data from the
>   client request. The application could check the data before eventually
>   overriting it with the response values.

Comment: Thanks hagrawal, it worked for me. exactly what i am looking for. :-)

Comment: Just want to understand the reason for moving your answer acceptance, I guess my answer was first and had everything needed for solving your problem ..