# How to get and set ref or out parameters in Python WSDL SOAP client

Tags: c#, python, soap, suds

Using Python with a SOAP client like Suds or Zeep, if I have an API with params defined as ref or out, how do I define them and read them.

e.g. a c# method defined so:

```
// this is c# code...
bool MyApi( 
  string regularParam1, 
  int regularParam2, 
  ref string refParam3, // set by caller, changed by service, 
                        // used as part of the result
  out string outParam4) // marked as 'out', caller not to set any value, 
                        // changed by service and used as part of the result
```

The soap would look so:

```
<soap:Body>
  <MyApi xmlns="http://mywebservice.myapi.com/">
    <regularParam1>string</regularParam1>
    <regularParam2>int</regularParam2>
    <refParam3>string</refParam3>
    <outParam4>string</outParam4>

<soap:Body>
  <MyApiResponse xmlns="http://mywebservice.myapi.com/">
    <MyApiResult>bool<MyApiResult>
    <refParam3>string</refParam3>
    <outParam4>string</outParam4>
```

I THINK (but not sure) that both the ref param and out param expect an object that will receive the result. The `out` content should be "empty" and the `ref` object's content can have a value. I have no idea how this works internally.

I went through [the list of Python SOAP frameworks in Samat Jain's excellent answer on a different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/what-soap-client-libraries-exist-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-for) but found no discussion on the topic in any of the listed frameworks.

The problem is that there are no `ref` or `out` params in python.

Instead, python function calls can return multiple values, and single argurments can contain multiple values (i.e. a tuple). But what do I do when that's how it's defined in the service, and in the SOAP?

a. How do I define these params in the calling client?  Do I have to do anything special, or just create regular parameters?

b. How do I get the resulting extra fields automatically (after defining them)? Or must I read the resulting SOAP xml and parse it myself?

Note: These `out` and `ref` parameters are part of the result, but are NOT part of the `return-value` which in the example above is a simple boolean.

c. If this cannot be done in Zeep or SUDS is there some other framework where it can be accomplished?

There is a [similar unanswered SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627283/how-do-i-pass-an-integer-variable-by-reference-in-python) (which I edited for clarity), but it is specific to a Zeep error that possibly is caused by ref params not defined correctly.

Comment: In Java they solved it by marking the parameters as in, out or inout. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904132/how-to-receive-and-send-with-same-parameter-name-in-java-soap

I have no idea what they do behind the scenes, but they too have no in/ref parameter definitions just like Python.

Comment: Is this basically the answer to my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327105/python-soap-zeep-module-get-result